# Strong Parameters requiring an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

Is it possible to mark a single attribute of a hash as required using strong parameters?

Given input like:

```
{
  "example" => {
    "optional": 1234,
    "required": 5678
   }
}
```

The standard strong params examples are:

`params.require(:example).permit(:optional, :required)`

Given that you can require certain parameters, I thought the following would work:

```
params.require(:example).require(:required)
params.require(:example).permit(:optional)
```

I've attempted:

```
params.require(:example => [ :required ]).permit(:optional)
params.require(:example).permit(:optional)
params[:example].require(:required)
```

And anything else I can think of.

Does anyone know if its possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Greg!

I had the same question, but after all I found, that its not appropriate question.

Look, here is the source code of require method in `strong_parameters` gem:

```
def require(key)
  self[key].presence || raise(ActionController::ParameterMissing.new(key))
end
```

So, basically, there is no way to require "required" attribute in params hash. But look on it from different side. I think its better write your own require method in order to do that. Since I'm using rails, I just added `validates_presence_of` to the model. If you want to make it dynamic, you may create custom validation. You can find its documentation here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations

Comment: Thanks RunFor. I came to the same conclusion. In my case the presence requirement is conditional on the way the resource is accessed (ie. via the controller) but I've been able to put in some conditional validation to help with this.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use

```
def example_params
  params.require(:example)
  params[:example].require(:required)
  params.require(:example).permit(:required, :optional)
end
```

The first line fails if `:example` is missing. The second line fails if `:required` is missing from `:example`. The third line returns what you expect, while allowing `:optional`.